# Re-apply jQuery filter when GridView reloads

Tags: jquery, gridview

Please can you help me with this.  I'm quite new to jQuery and can't get this one to work.

I found a sample jQuery script somewhere online. It works OK in filtering the rows in an ASP.net GridView. 
The problem is that having found a row (the grid gets nicely truncated and shows just the one I want), if I press one of the .net command buttons like edit, the page reloads and the jQuery filtering is lost.  I have to press the search button again.
Code is below.

I've tried various onload or document-ready functions and they don't work - either they do nothing when the page is reloaded, or they unapply the filter.

Please show me how to make it automatically re-apply the filter once the page reloads to action an edit on the data grid.

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%=lblNoRecords.ClientID%>').css('display','none');

    $('#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').click(function(e)
    {
        $('#<%=lblNoRecords.ClientID%>').css('display','none'); // Hide No records to display label.
        $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").hide(); // Hide all the rows.

        var iCounter = 0;
        var sSearchTerm = $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').val(); //Get the search box value

        if(sSearchTerm.length == 0) //if nothing is entered then show all the rows.
        {
          $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").show(); 
          return false;
        }
        //Iterate through all the td.
        $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").children().each(function() 
        {
            var cellText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            if(cellText.indexOf(sSearchTerm.toLowerCase()) >= 0) //Check if data matches
            {    
                $(this).parent().show();
                iCounter++;
                return true;
            } 
        });
        if(iCounter == 0)
        {
            $('#<%=lblNoRecords.ClientID%>').css('display','');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    })
})
</script>



    Search Text :
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Search" /> 

<br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" >
.....
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to detect the presence of a search term and search automatically in `document.ready()`.   Basically re-applying the filter again because the action link you clicked posted back to the server, and your filter only ran when a button is clicked.

Here I have refactored your code to extract the filter function and added an if to the bottom of your `document.ready()` function that will reapply the filter in the case that the search field is not empty.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%=lblNoRecords.ClientID%>').css('display','none');

    $('#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').click(function(e)
    {
        filterGrid($('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').val()); 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    if($('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').val().trim() !== ""){ // was I filtering?
        filterGrid($('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').val());
    }
})
function filterGrid(term){
    $('#<%=lblNoRecords.ClientID%>').css('display','none'); // Hide No records to display label.
    $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").hide(); // Hide all the rows.

    var iCounter = 0;
    var sSearchTerm = term //Get the search box value

    if(sSearchTerm.length == 0) //if nothing is entered then show all the rows.
    {
      $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").show(); 
      return false;
    }
    //Iterate through all the td.
    $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").children().each(function() 
    {
        var cellText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        if(cellText.indexOf(sSearchTerm.toLowerCase()) >= 0) //Check if data matches
        {    
            $(this).parent().show();
            iCounter++;
            return true;
        } 
    });
    if(iCounter == 0)
    {
        $('#<%=lblNoRecords.ClientID%>').css('display','');
    }
}
```